Unable to Add Location Tag on Instagram for My Business Hi everyone,
I manage the social media accounts for a business located in Benevento, Italy, called "Enoteca Elisa". While I'm able to add the location tag (geo-tag) for our business on Facebook posts and stories without any issues, and from meta business suit when programming posts, I'm having trouble doing the same on Instagram. The location does not appear as an option on Instagram, even though the address is correct and the location is set up properly on Facebook.
Here are the steps I have already taken to try and resolve this issue:
Verified Location on Facebook:
The location is correctly created and associated with our business on Facebook.
Updated Details on Facebook:
All details such as address, name, and category are correct and complete on the Facebook page of Enoteca Elisa.
Synchronized Instagram with Facebook:
Our Instagram account is correctly linked to our Facebook page.
Tried Adding Location on Instagram:
When creating a story or post on Instagram, I searched for the exact name of the location as it appears on Facebook, but it doesn’t show up.
Attempted to add the location manually on Instagram but this is not possible.
Updated Apps:
Both Facebook and Instagram apps are updated to the latest versions.
Checked Location Settings:
Verified that the location services on my device are active and that Instagram has permission to access the location.
Despite all these efforts, the problem persists. I have also checked the Meta support community, but couldn't find a solution.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
